# 1950's or 60's TV Show About Anti Gravity Rings or Stones

Tags: story-identification, tv

I remember watching a black and white TV show where two men find a set of rings (or stones, I don't recall) and anything placed between them would levitate. It had a very Twilight Zone feel to it and I think it was from the same era.

The other option, of course, is that my young self had an active imagination. If anyone has any insight I'd love to find out if this show existed!

Answer (score 6):

So this is funny. I typed my exact headline into a search, except with a typo. (Riongs instead of rings.) The typo served up the answer at the top of the page. Without the typo...I've been searching for months!

Anyhow, it's a story from Science Fiction Theatre called "The Stones Began to Move." It was actually color and not black and white. One of a small number of series shot in color in the 1950's.

At least I'm not crazy...

Comment: Congrats! You can accept answers by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour]. As a self-answer, you have to wait 48 hours from the time you asked, so in about 47 hours (really, two days), you'll be able to accept this by clicking on the checkmark.